# Bash: extract text in between two characters which appears more than once

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which contains the nodes and edges of a graph in the form of triples. Each line has 3 triples, but sometimes there is text in between or at the end:

```
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
<samplenode> sometimestheristextinbetween<sampleEdge> <samplenode> and sometimes more at the end
<samplenode> <samplereEdge> <samplenode>
```

I need a command which only prints the triples and ignores the text in between. So it should only contain characters in between `<>`

It can include `<`and `>` or not. That doesn`t matter, but it should be seperated. The result could look like this:

```
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode> 
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
```

I tried it with `sed`, deleting everything in between two patterns (everything between `>`and `<`) but it never worked the way i wanted it.

Does anyone have a solution for me? Maybe with `grep`or `awk`?

Greetings

Comment: Is it ok to leave a space at the end of the line?

Comment: Can `<` or `>` appear in any other context, e.g. within the `sometimestheristextinbetween` text?

Comment: @PaulHodges yes it is ok.

Comment: @EdMorton No they dont appear in any other context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for FPAT and assuming neither `<` nor `>` appears in any other context:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='<[^>]+>' '{$1=$1}1' file
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
<samplenode> <samplereEdge> <samplenode>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some awk play with the separators, tested with the sample input.

```
awk -v RS="<" -F">" '{printf $1 (NR%3==1? "\n": " ")}' file

samplenode sampleEdge samplenode
samplenode sampleEdge samplenode
samplenode samplereEdge samplenode
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep -o` will print just the matched parts of the line (one match per line of output) and then you can use `paste` to columnize the result into three columns. This depends on there being exactly three matches per line.

```
$ grep -o '<[^>]*>' file | paste - - -
<samplenode>        <sampleEdge>        <samplenode>
<samplenode>        <sampleEdge>        <samplenode>
<samplenode>        <samplereEdge>      <samplenode>
```

Comment: if you only want a single space delimiter, add `-s\ ` or `-s' '`

Comment: This works, but if there are more than 23 characters in between `<>` it will cut everything after the 23rd character.

Comment: Thanks, @SBKIT, that's not a very nice feature of `pr` at all for this use case. Updated to use `paste` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The following looks like enough:

```
sed 's/[^>]*\(<[^>]*>\)[^<]*/\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^.*(<[^<>]*>).*(<[^<>]*>).*\1.*$/\1 \2 \1/' file
```

Pattern match on the triplet (where the first is also the third) and replace only the matches space separated.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with following `awk` approach, could you please try following should work in any kind of `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  val=""
  while(match($0,/<[^>]*/)){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  }
  print val
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  val=""                                                   ##Nullifying val here.
  while(match($0,/<[^>]*/)){                               ##Running whole loop and mentioning match inside it to match everything from < till very first occurence of > in current line.
    val=(val?val OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)        ##Creating val which has sub-string of matched part here.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)                         ##Re-creating current line where already matched part is removed.
  }
  print val                                                ##Printing val here.
}' Input_file                                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variant of `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/>[^<]*(<*)/> \1/g'
```

This matches from the closing tag to either the open of another (or the end of line), and replaces with close, space, and anything that matched the test for another open (so empty at EOL).

Use whichever reads and makes sense better for you.

If you'd rather not use `-E`xtended pattern matching, then

```
sed 's/>[^<]*\(<*\)/> \1/g'
```

If you don't want the space at EOL, add a trim.

```
sed -E 's/>[^<]*(<*)/> \1/g; s/ $//;'
```

Comment: Non-GNU may not allow semicolons, but you can replace them with newlines.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {b="<";e=">";FS="["b e"]"} 
             {for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ", b $i e; print ""}' file

<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
<samplenode> <sampleEdge> <samplenode>
<samplenode> <samplereEdge> <samplenode>
```